# What does Heidegger mean by the "whole of Dasein"/the "totality of Dasein"/ "Being-a-whole" ,etc. in Division 2 of Being and Time?

Tags: heidegger, being-and-time

At the beginning of Division 2, Heidegger motivates his account of death, conscience, and the temporality of care by saying that Division 1 failed to account for the "whole of Dasein" / the "totality of Dasein" / "Being-a-whole". I've been following Hubert Dreyfus' lectures on Division 2, and even he expresses his confusion at this expression. Given the pivotal role of this concept in Division 2, it seems like it must be important for Heidegger, yet I have no clue what it means.

Can someone say what this concept means, and why is it so important in motivating his account of death, conscience, and the temporality of care?

Comment: Division 1's everyday isolated Dasein's analytic existence as being-towards-death doesn't fully account for the holistic meta nature of complete human existence aka whole of Dasein. Facing death, conscience, and the temporality of care, the deepity of whole of Dasein (being here or there) becomes necessary to understand all of them. The indefinite being-towards-death in itself doesn't account for the 'there' after death that cannot be simply nothingness since nothingness is being-not-yet by definition it doesn't connect with other Daseins in its totality which could be further accounted for...

Comment: This is a great question for which an answer, imo, heavily involves the structural and factice (from "facticity") aspects of the Dasein. The proper terms for thos in SuZ are respectively "existential" and "existentiell". This answer I wrote some times ago gives a quick overview of their meaning: https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/96903/does-being-with-others-have-an-antonym/97383#97383 - I'll try to write a proposition of answer when I get the impetus